# Entity framework required field does not accept space

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a simple SQL Server table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table3]
(
    [PK] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [field1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL DEFAULT (' '),
    [field2] [varchar](1) NOT NULL DEFAULT (' '), 

    CONSTRAINT [Table3_PrimaryKey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([PK] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In SQL Server, the following queries are valid:

```
   INSERT INTO Table3
   VALUES (1, 'Test1', ' ')

   INSERT INTO Table3
   VALUES (2, 'Test2', '')

   INSERT INTO Table3 (PK, field1)
   VALUES (3, 'Test3')

   INSERT INTO Table3
   VALUES (4, 'Test4', 'X')
```

I have created a console application with Entity Framework 6 code first. When I try to add a new record, the insert fails with "Required field" error. It seems a space is not valid for field2, but in SQL it's legal.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          try
          {
            using (Model1 ctx = new Model1())
            {
                ctx.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
                Table3 t3 = new Table3();
                t3.PK = 1;
                t3.field1 = "Test";
                t3.field2 = " ";
                ctx.Table3.Add(t3);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
          }
          catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
          {
              Console.Write(ex.Message);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              Console.Write(ex.Message);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Model

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  using System;
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
  using System.Linq;

  public partial class Model1 : DbContext
  {
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model11")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Table3> Table3 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table3>()
            .Property(e => e.field1)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Table3>()
            .Property(e => e.field2)
            .IsUnicode(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Table

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
  using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

  public partial class Table3
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PK { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string field1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string field2 { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Thanks
Michele

Comment: Side-note: a `varchar(1)` datatype is pretty useless.... since it's a variable-length column, it will have a 2 byte overhead - just to store one or no character.... so it will use 2 or 3 bytes (to store a max. of 1 character).... if you have strings of 5 characters or less, I'd always recommend using `char(n)` since that really only stores that many characters as you define - `char(1)` will store 1 byte only, for one character (or none).

Comment: I guess the big question is: why on earth do you want to store a single space!!

Comment: I made it simple, but the real table is more complex. I can't modify the database structure, I just need to use it as is. I am only curious to know why Entity Framework is different from normal SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's an old post. I had this similar problem today. I found that adding `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` helped.